# photo gallery implementation like tmz

Tags: images, gallery

** REVISED POST **

I have a **custom post type** called `photo_group` that allows you to input an *array* of photos. I also have a single post called "photos" which is **re-written** to be my-website.com/photos  When a user goes to the photos page I want the *first* (and only **one**) `photo_group` to display it's content in a **photo gallery** (I'll take recommendations here, but I can simply drop in a JS photo gallery as needed). I was going to build something *custom* for this, but I don't know that that is *necessary*.

I don't want to build this with custom code and then find out I could have used nextgen or something like it. The goal is to have something similar to [TMZ's photo page](http://photos.tmz.com/). Thanks.

** ORIGNAL POST **

I'm thinking I'm probably going to have to do this by finagling my php to output some javascript, but I don't want to be in the middle of doing that and find out there was an easier way.

I have a custom post type called `photo_group` and I'm trying to use it to accomplish something like [TMZ's photo page](http://photos.tmz.com/). Thanks.

PS- I don't do celebrity gossip so rest assure this isn't for me!

** ANSWER **

I ended up doing a custom php implementation with using a [jQuery slideViewer](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/imagestrip/imageslide-plugin.html) for the front end.

Comment: You need to be more clear on what you want, just linking to a page and saying " I want this" provides little incentive for getting an answer.

Comment: I made a revised post in hopes that I'm not seen as someone just looking for a hand out. I merely need to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sliders and photo stuff you best bet is to code it yourself, especially in your situation where your grabbing photos from one area (CPT) and displaying them in another.

It's fairly simple to find a good js image slider/gallery and then just drop `WP Query` into it.

You can of course browse here and see if any have a shortcode that allows you to run a query as well.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/slideshow